# Wow, that's a big workbook. Unfortunately, we can't open a workbook larger than 10 MB

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerpivot

I use `Share Point 2013` and `PowerPivot Service` .

I create a report in `Excel` and Upload my report in SharePoint Document but when I want visit this report in my SharePoint web site, I get this error :

```
Wow, that's a big workbook. Unfortunately, 
we can't open a workbook larger than 10 MB.

You'll need to open this in Excel.
```

[image]

How I can change max size of Excel Report in `sharepoint`?

Comment: Did you try this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487972.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure if you ever got the response you needed but here it is.

FYI The posted before told you how to change the upload size restriction (can I upload a 10mb doc/xls or a 1GB doc/xls)  and not how to correct the workbook setting within Central Admin so that that display a workbook in a web part (browser) using Excel Services.

1. Log in to Central Admin as a Farm Administrator
2. Click “Application Management” in the left nav.
3. Click “Manage service applications” under Service Applications.
4. Click “Excel Services Application” next to “Excel Services Application Web Service Application”  Note: not the item in grey under this.. You want the blue item.
5. Click the “Trusted File Locations” link and then select the reports library or document library your web part is calling or where the files are.
6. Scroll down to “Workbook Properties” and change the ‘Maximum Workbook Size” if it’s set to 10mb’s try and change it to 50 or 100mb’s and save the change.
7. Go back to the page with the reports web part and refresh it.

This should fix your issue with “This workbook is larger than the maximum workbook size allowed to be opened in the browser" and Excel Services in SharePoint 2010.

Here’s a link to help you out.

Thanks - Kris Wagner

TechNet - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191192.aspx

Comment: Glad to know it helps you :)